# RabbitMQ Java client to Windows Service Bus

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, servicebus

Is it possible to use RabbitMQ Java client to work directly with Windows Service Bus via AMQP?

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj841072.aspx), supported Java clients are:

- Apache Qpid Java Message Service (JMS) client
- IIT SwiftMQ Java client

Has anyone tried the RabbitMQ Java Client?

Comment: If you are asking about https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html - yes, a lot of users here on SO use it (just search by tags `java` and `rabbitmq`)

Comment: Yes, that's the client I was asking about. I was searching the SO before, but I have just found RabbitMQ supports AMQP 0.9.1, whilst Windows Service Bus supports AMQP 1.0 (according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258792/ampq-v1-0-client-for-net and https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Azure Service Bus uses AMQP 1.0 and the RabbitMQ Java Client is compliant to AMQP 0.9.1 using concepts like exchange and binding (other than queue). All above concepts were removed in the new AMQP 1.0 specification. It means that you can't use RabbitMQ Java Client to access Service Bus in Azure.

Paolo.